# How to fix this error with npm run for react?

Tags: reactjs

I got error when I did npm start for react in very beginning.

Please help me out how to fix it

```
(base) jakes-air:try_app juyounglee$ npm start

npm ERR! file /Users/juyounglee/Documents/try_app/package.json

npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json

npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected token } in JSON at position 259 while parsing near '...t-scripts build",
npm ERR! JSON.parse   },

npm ERR! JSON.parse   "eslintConfig":...'

npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.

npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /Users/juyounglee/.npm/_logs/2019-09-12T19_24_04_265Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Your `package.json` file contains invalid JSON syntax.

Comment: Please paste your `package.json` file here as well and we can help you. The error says that at line 259 you have a problem in your `package.json` file.

Comment: Package.json no 259line
{
  "name": "try_app_2019",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}

Comment: @JuyoungLee post your `package.json` in your question. edit your question. don't post it in the comments because it's not understandable

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your package.json file is invalid. Try to figure-out what exactly wrong with any online service for JSON validation (for example https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com)